# "For a given string, return the next character after every letter 'r' ". A ruby kickstart tutorial challenge (1:7)

Tags: ruby, string, loops

The exercise has this following solution:

```
def pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr(string)
    to_return = ""
    add_next = false

    string.size.times do |index|
        current_char = string[index]
        to_return << current_char if add_next
        add_next = (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
    end

    to_return
end
```

And I have already asked Josh Cheek (the instructor) to clarify it but he seems to be a little inactive these days. I just want a layman's explanation on some things.

1. Doesn't the `to_return` variable getting `current_char` value means it is getting the string "r" itself instead of the next?
2. Why is the `add_next` set to `false` initially? I have tested this code by giving a string which starts with "r" and it still works.
3. Can it be done with `next if` method?

Actually, if it's not a problem, if someone please explain the whole code to me that would be just perfect!

Comment: Those attempting to answer this question - please also look at test cases of this problem here : https://github.com/JoshCheek/ruby-kickstart/blob/master/session1/spec/7.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to understand code like this—and a lot of other code—is to pretend you're the computer. Write down the variable names and their values, then go through each line of code just like the computer would, doing what the computer would do. Usually pencil and paper or whiteboard is easiest, but since we're not in the same room we'll have to type it out.

> Here's how our method starts if we call it with the
>   argument `"Rare"`:
>
> ```ruby
> string = "Rare"
> to_return = ""
> add_next = false
> ```
>
> We set `add_next` to `false` because we will never add the first
>   character (in this case `"R"`) to the output (because the first
>   character never follows an `"r"`—it never follows anything!).
>
> Now we go into the loop. To understand the code, we'll manually
>   "unroll" the loop—that is, since the loop has four iterations for our
>   input, we'll write down the code inside the loop four times. Since the
>   value of `index` increments with every iteration, instead of
>   `string[index]` I've written `string[0]`, `string[1]`, etc. After each
>   line I've written, in a comment, the same line again, but with the
>   variables replaced by their values.
>
> ```ruby
> current_char = string[0]
> # => current_char = "R"
>
> to_return << current_char if add_next
> # => to_return << "R" if false
> # => (do nothing; to_return is still ""))
>
> add_next = (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
> # => add_next = ("R" == "r" || "R" == "R")
> # => add_next = (false || true)
> # => add_next = true
> ```
>
> Our first iteration is done. We didn't add anything to `to_return`,
>   but since this character was `"R"` we set `add_next` to `true` so in
>   the *next* iteration we'll know to add a character to `to_return`.
>
> Now, the second iteration:
>
> ```ruby
> current_char = string[1]
> # => current_char = "a"
>
> to_return << current_char if add_next
> # => to_return << "a" if true
> # => (to_return is now "a")
>
> add_next = (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
> # => add_next = ("a" == "r" || "a" == "R")
> # => add_next = (false || false)
> # => add_next = false
> ```
>
> In the second iteration we added `"a"` to `to_return` because we had
>   set `add_next` to `true` in the first iteration. Then we set
>   `add_next` to `false` because this character was not an `"r"`.
>
> Now, the third iteration.
>
> ```ruby
> current_char = string[2]
> # => current_char = "r"
>
> to_return << current_char if add_next
> # => to_return << "r" if false
> # => (do nothing; to_return is still "a")
>
> add_next = (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
> # => add_next = ("r" == "r" || "r" == "R")
> # => add_next = (true || false)
> # => add_next = true
> ```
>
> In the third iteration we didn't add anything to `to_return` because
>   we had set `add_next` to `false` in the second iteration. Then we set
>   `add_next` to `true` because `current_char` was `"r"`, so in the next
>   iteration we'll know to add a character to `to_return`.
>
> Now, the fourth and final iteration.
>
> ```ruby
> current_char = string[3]
> # => current_char = "e"
>
> to_return << current_char if add_next
> # => to_return << "e" if true
> # => (to_return is now "ae")
>
> add_next = (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
> # => add_next = ("e" == "r" || "e" == "R")
> # => add_next = (false || false)
> # => add_next = false
> ```
>
> In the fourth iteration we added `"e"` to `to_return` because we had
>   set `add_next` to `true` in the third iteration.
>
> Since this was the last iteration, the rest doesn't really matter. The
>   final value of `to_return` is `"ae"`.

I hope that helps you understand what the method does. In answer to your questions:

1. > Doesn't the `to_return` variable getting `current_char` value means it is getting the string "r" itself instead of the next?

   No, because we add (or don't add) a character to `to_return` based in the value of `add_next` that we set in the *previous* iteration. If the previous character was an `"r"`, `add_next` will be `true` and we'll add the current character (the one that comes *after* the `"r"`) to `to_return`.
2. > Why is the `add_next` set to `false` initially? I have tested this code by giving a string which starts with "r" and it still works.

   Because we never add the first character to `to_return`, because the first character never follows an `"r"`—it never follows anything!
3. > Can it be done with `next if` method?

   It would be a little tricky to use in this case. The natural thing to do would be to use `next unless ...` to skip the code where you add a character to `to_return` when `add_next` was set to `false` in a previous iteration. But if you do that, where will you set the value of `add_next` for the next iteration? If you skip one, you end up skipping both. You could still do it by, say, setting a temporary variable, but it's messy:

   ```ruby
   string.size.times do |index|
     current_char = string[index]
     add_current = add_next
     add_next = (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
     next unless add_current
     to_return << current_char
   end
   ```

   Probably not worth it in this case.

### P.S.

One thing I love about Ruby (that some people hate) is that there's more than one way to do anything. Here's another way to solve this particular exercise:

```ruby
def say_arr(string)
  string.each_char.each_cons(2)
    .with_object("") do |(a,b), to_return|
      next unless a.downcase == "r"
      to_return << b
    end
end
```

What this does is take each consecutive pair (`each_cons(2)`) of characters (in the case of `"Rare"`, `"Ra"`, `"ar"`, and `"re"`) and looks at the first character in the pair, and if it's an `"r"`, it adds the second character in the pair to `to_return`.

### P.P.S.

Four months later: Just for kicks, I wanted to describe how this can be solved very concisely using regular expressions.

The strongest tool in our arsenal for extracting all of the matches out of a string is [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-scan). A naïve approach (and the first thing I tried) would be to use `String#scan` with the regular expression `/r./i`, which should (at first blush) match every `r` (or `R`) and the character that follows it (`.`). But it doesn't quite work:

```ruby
"ArrBrrC".scan(/r./i)
# => [ "rr", "rr" ]
```

We expect four matches: `rr`, `rB`, `rr`, and `rC`; but we only get two. That's because after each match the regular expression engine advances its "cursor" by the number of the characters in the match. After it matches the first `rr`, the cursor is at offset 3, the `B` characters. It never has a chance to match `rB`!

The solution is to use the *positive lookbehind* feature, which the [Regexp docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) describe thusly:

> `(?<=pat)` - *Positive lookbehind* assertion: ensures that the preceding characters match `pat`, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

Armed with this knowledge, we can construct the regular expression `/(?<=r)./i`:

```ruby
"ArrBrrC".scan(/(?<=r)./i)
# => ["r", "B", "r", "C"]
```

This works perfectly! Since the preceding `r`s aren't included in the match, the length of the match is only 1, so the cursor is advanced by one character each time and no matches are skipped! All we need to do is put it in a method, and join the matches together into a single string:

```ruby
def say_arr(string)
  string.scan(/(?<=r)./i).join
end

p say_arr("ArrBrrC") # => "rBrC"
p say_arr("Rare horror mirror!") # => "aero ro!"
```

I wonder, though, if we could do this without `Array#join`. Can we use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) to just remove every character that *doesn't* follow an `r`? Indeed we can, by using the opposite of positive lookbehind: *negative lookbehind*!

> `(?<!pat)` - *Negative lookbehind* assertion: ensures that the preceding characters do not match `pat`, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

We can use it like this:

```ruby
def say_arr(string)
  string.gsub(/(?<!r)./i, '')
end

p say_arr("Rare horror mirror!") # => "aero ro!"
p say_arr("Grr, orrery errors") # => "r,reyros"
```

Neat!

Comment: This is overwhelmingly good!! May god bless you in every possible way.

Answer (score 2):

To get what the program is doing, you can start with a concrete example (eg. `pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("rarbrcrd")`), and run the code **in mind** line by line. Probably, you will need some paper to write down some intermediate result for each of the variable. I found this helpful at the beginning of studying programming.

Do make sure you get what each line is doing when you go through the example. Reason about the following:

1. What this line is doing?
2. What effect does it have for the following code?
3. What data is changed after this line?

It will be hard at the beginning, sooner or later you will find it's pretty straight forward as you practice more and more.

You can print the intermediate result for each variable involved in each step, so that you can verify the result got in your mind.

```
def rates_say_arrrrrrrrr(string)
  to_return = ""
  add_next = false

  string.size.times do |index|
    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = #{index}"
    current_char = string[index]
    puts "current_char = #{current_char}"
    to_return << current_char if add_next
    puts "to_return = #{to_return}, add_next = #{add_next}"
    add_next = (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
    puts "add_next = #{add_next}"
  end

  to_return
end

result = rates_say_arrrrrrrrr("rarbrcrd")
puts result
```

The result looks like the following:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 0
current_char = r
to_return = , add_next = false
add_next = true
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 1
current_char = a
to_return = a, add_next = true
add_next = false
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 2
current_char = r
to_return = a, add_next = false
add_next = true
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 3
current_char = b
to_return = ab, add_next = true
add_next = false
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 4
current_char = r
to_return = ab, add_next = false
add_next = true
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 5
current_char = c
to_return = abc, add_next = true
add_next = false
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 6
current_char = r
to_return = abc, add_next = false
add_next = true
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> index = 7
current_char = d
to_return = abcd, add_next = true
add_next = false
abcd
```

Put some marks for each iteration so that you see the boundary (`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`).

This is some raw debug technique. Later when you're familiar with the language and its libraries, you can use some debugging tools such as byebug, pry-debug, etc.

To answer you questions:

1. `to_return << current_char if add_next` is a post conditional statement. It's like

   ```
   if add_next
     to_return << current_char
   end
   ```

   so it will only add `current_char` when `add_next` is true.
2. If `add_next` isn't false initially, the first character will be added to `to_current` regardless whether it should be or not. `add_next` will be updated in each iteration, and be used in the later iteration.
3. There is (always) more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For a given input `string`, the goal of the program is to create another string comprising of characters that are present just after the characters `r` and `R`.

A simplified version of the program could have been like this, here we get rid of confusing variable `add_next`.

```
def pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr(string)
    to_return = ""

    string.size.times do |index|
        current_char = string[index]
        next_char = string[index + 1] || ''

        to_return << next_char if (current_char == "r" || current_char == "R")
    end

    to_return
end

p pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("are you really learning Ruby?")
p pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("Katy Perry is on the radio!")
p pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("Pirates say arrrrrrrrr")
p pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("r1r2r")
p pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("")
p pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("Quickly she consumed the apple.")
```

**Output** [as expected](https://github.com/JoshCheek/ruby-kickstart/blob/master/session1/spec/7.rb)

```
"eenu"
"rya"
"arrrrrrrr"
"12"
""
""
```

Comment: That's what I couldn't figure out, that empty string following 'or'. How stupid of me. Thank you very much. And sorry I didn't include that tutorial directly which you had to go through!!